# The intuition behind this explicit form of an affine hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof, convex-geometry, affine-geometry

I have come across an explicit formula of an affine hull from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull). I'm trying to prove that formula in **2.** below. However, my approach is quite muscular and not natural, i.e. I have to know the formula beforehand in order to prove it.

Could you elaborate on an intuition behind such formula and another approach to obtain that it?

---

Let $V$ be a vector space. A set $A \subset V$ is called an affine subspace if $A = S+a$ for some vector subspace $S\subset V$ and $a\in V$.

> 1. Let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a collection of affine subspaces of $V$. Then $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$ is also an affine subspace.

Assume $A_i = S_i + a_i$ for some vector subspace $S_i \subset V$ and $a_i\in V$. If $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i = \emptyset$. Then we are done. If not, there is $x \in \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$. It's clear that $A_i = x+S_i$. Then $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i = \bigcap_{i\in I} (x+S_i) = x+\bigcap_{i\in I} S_i$. Because $\bigcap_{i\in I} S_i$ is a vector subspace, the claim then follows.

> 2. Let $B \subset V$. The affine hull of $B$, denoted by $\operatorname{aff} (B)$ is defined as the smallest affine subspace containing $B$. Then
>    $$
>    \operatorname{aff}(B)= C:=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} x_{i} \,\middle\vert\, k \in \mathbb N^*, x_{i} \in B, a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i}=1\right\}.
>    $$

- First, we show that $C$ is indeed an affine subspace.

We fix some $b \in B$. We will show that $C-b$ is a vector subspace. Let $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in C$, i.e.,
$$
c_j = \sum_{i=1}^{k_j} a_{j,i} x_{j,i}
$$
with $k_j \in \mathbb N^*, x_{j,i} \in B, a_{j,i} \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{k_j} a_{j,i}=1$.

It suffices to show that $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j (c_j-b)  \in C-b$ for any $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb R$. This is equivalent to showing that $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j (c_j-b) +b \in C$. In fact, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j (c_j-b) +b &= \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{k_j} a_{j,i} x_{j,i} - b \right) +b \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \sum_{i=1}^{k_j}  a_{j,i} x_{j,i} + \left (1- \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\right)b.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $\sum_{i=1}^{k_j} a_{j,i}=1$, so the sum of coefficients is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \sum_{i=1}^{k_j}  a_{j,i} + \left (1- \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j + \left (1- \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\right) = 1.
$$

- Second, we show that if $A$ is a affine subspace containing $B$, then $A$ contains $C$.

Assume $A = S+a$ for some vector subspace $S\subset V$ and $a\in V$. Let $c\in C$, i.e., $c=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} x_{i}$ with $k \in \mathbb N^*, x_{i} \in B, a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i}=1$. To prove that $c\in A$, we will show that $c-a \in S$. We have
$$
c-a = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} x_{i}-a = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} (x_{i}-a).
$$

We have $B \subset A = S+a$, so $B-a \subset S$. Hence $x_i-a \in S$. The claim then follows.

Comment: The intuition for two points is that the set of [convex combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) is the segment between them, and the set of [affine combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination) is the line through them. Then it "scales up" from there.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you so much for your enlightening comment. Now I got it.

Comment: Computer scientists are fond of the function "lerp" (short for "linear interpolation" somehow), defined by ${\rm lerp}_t(a,b)=a(1-t)+bt=a+(b-a)t$. For whatever reason, while it is common in computer science (see [this video](https://youtu.be/aVwxzDHniEw) for an example), most mathematicians have not heard of it (by that name, I mean).

Comment: My personal intuition is to think of a "standard affine space" consisting of all points in $\Bbb R^n$ whose first coordinate is $1$:$$A=\{(1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\mid x_2,\dots,x_n\in\Bbb R\}.$$An affine combination is any linear combination that keeps you in $A$. Now it's clearer why the $\alpha_i$s in Wikipedia need to add to $1$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dxiv's comment, the idea gets clearer to me. It lies in the characterization of an affine subspace by affine combination.

---

Let $V$ be a vector space. A set $A \subset V$ is called *affine* (subspace) if $A = S+a$ for some vector subspace $S\subset V$ and $a\in V$. The following statements are equivalent.

1. $A$ is affine
2. $\forall x,y\in A, \forall t\in \mathbb R: tx+(1-t)y \in A$.
3. $\forall x_i \in A, \forall t_i \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \sum_i t_i=1: \sum_i t_i x_i \in A$.

The proof $(2) \iff (3)$ is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1931820/368425).

> a. $(1) \implies (2)$.

Assume $A$ is affine, i.e., $A = S+a$ for some vector subspace $S\subset V$ and $a\in V$. Let $x,y\in A$. Then $x=s_1+a$ and $y=s_2+a$ for some $s_1, s_2\in S$. For all $t\in \mathbb R$, we get
$$
tx+(1-t)y = t(s_1+a)+(1-t)(s_2+a) = [ts_1+(1-t)s_2] +a \in S+a=A.
$$

> b. $(2) \implies (1)$.

Assume $A$ such that
$$
\forall x,y\in A, \forall t\in \mathbb R: tx+(1-t)y \in A.
$$

We fix some $a\in A$. We will prove that $S:=A-a$ is a vector subspace. For all $t_1,t_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $a_1, a_2\in A$, we have
$$
t_1(a_1-a)+t_2(a_2-a) = t_1a_1+t_2a_2+[1-(t_1+t_2)]a-a \in A-a
$$
This is because $t_1+t_2 + [1-(t_1+t_2)]=1$ and thus $t_1a_1+t_2a_2+[1-(t_1+t_2)]a\in A$.